# Sepscatter () and lowess smoothing (Stata)

Tags: stata, scatter-plot

I have the following the code, which works well, but I want to also add lowess smoothing to the scatter and also keep the regional labels.

```
sepscatter  avg_unemp log_avg_gdp,  separate(region) addplot(lfit avg_unemp log_avg_gdp)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2EUK.png)

I found this option, but I want to keep all regions in one scatter, rather than a scatter plot per region.

```
twoway scatter avg_unemp log_avg_gdp, mcolor(*.6) ||
lfit avg_unemp log_avg_gdp ||
lowess avg_unemp log_avg_gdp ||, by(region)
```

Fixed the issue with Nick's suggestion:

```
sepscatter  avg_unemp log_avg_gdp, separate(region) addplot(lowess avg_unemp log_avg_gdp if region=="Middle East & North Africa" | region=="Latin America & Caribbean" | region=="Europe & Central Asia" | region=="Sub-Saharan Africa" | region=="East Asia & Pacific" | region==" South Asia" | region=="North America ")
```

Comment: `sepscatter` doesn't offer any special handles for `lowess`. You need to spell out separate `lowess` calls for each region (in your case) within `addplot()`.  Otherwise -- given that this forum is billed as for professional and enthusiast programmers -- you need to write your own program, and `sepscatter` might be a good start.

Comment: Good if you got what you wanted to get, but your extra code looks like a `lowess` for everything, which is not what I guessed you to mean.